# Overlay directory in buildroot does not write to /var

Tags: linux, buildroot

I specified a buildroot overlay directory and put some files to the var directory. This does not appear to be in the final root tar directory. Every other directory like etc works fine but not var. I need this to create the dpkg folders required to install new packages for my deployed software which must be updateable.